# JPA Map<enum,entity> using Hibernate and MySQL, enum key shows as null in database column

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dictionary, enums

I'm using a Map with enum key, and entity value. However, when created in MySQL dbs, the enum key column is always null. Could anyone help to explain?

```
public enum Type{
    A,B,C
}

@Entity
public class Item{
....
.....
        @ManyToOne
    public Container getContainer() {
        return container;
    }

}

@Entity
public class Container {

....
....
        @OneToMany (mappedBy="container")   // bi-directional relation
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING) 
    @MapKeyColumn(name="type", length = 20, nullable = true) 
    public Map<Type, Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

Also for MapKeyColumn annotation, I can't use **nullable=false** which is default.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using ElementCollection annotation instead along with CollectionTable annotation for the joining table.